# What's the problem in gap algorithm code ? (Code available below)

Tags: c++, sorting

I studied the gap algorithm(merging without extra space) but after coding, it looks ok to me but it is not giving a correct answer or maybe an error, please check out my code and it would be very helpful if you guys can tell me what's wrong.

`arr1` and `arr2` are sorted arrays of `n` and `m` sizes respectively, I excluded the driver code.

main() function is just taking input of sorted arrays arr1 and arr2 and then after implementing the merge function it is printing the values of arr1 and arr2 which expected to be sorted as merged array

**This is the algorithm - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficiently-merging-two-sorted-arrays-with-o1-extra-space/**

```
Example - arr1 = {1, 3, 5, 7}
           arr2 = {0 , 2 , 6, 8, 9}
expected output - arr1 = {0,1,2,3}
                  arr2 = {5,6,7,8,9}
observed output - Nothing it just crashes.
```

```
void merge(int arr1[], int arr2[], int n, int m) {
    int soa = (n+m);
    int gap;
    if(soa%2 == 0){
        gap = soa/2;
    }
    else{
        gap = (soa+1)/2;
    }
    for(int g = gap; g >= 1; g/2){
    for(int i = 0; i < soa; i++){
        int j = i + g;
        if(j >= soa){
            break;
        }
        if(j < n){
            if(arr1[i] > arr1[j]){
                swap(arr1[i],arr1[j]);
            }
        }
            else if(j >= n && i < n){
                if(arr1[i] > arr2[j - n]){
                    swap(arr1[i],arr2[j-n]);
                }
            }
            else if(i >= n && j >= n){
                if(arr2[i - n] > arr2[j - n]){
                    swap(arr2[i - n], arr2[j - n]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Give us the expected behavior, the observed behavior, and most import a minimal working example[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example], i.e.g the main function that allows others to see what you have seen..

Comment: please you tell us what is wrong. Please include a [mcve] together with example input, output and expected output in the question. If you get errors, please include the error message in the question

Comment: @WhozCraig initializing soa (size of arr1 + size of arr2) and then initializing gap. Actually, this is a gap algorithm for merging two sorted arrays without extra space.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am new here it will take me some time.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited it now, I only wanted to initialize gap variable quickly.

Comment: I don't understand from your example what the algorithm is supposed to do.

Comment: Hmm..., code contains `for(int g = gap; g >= 1; g/2){` ... `g/2` is just a *discarded expression*. Could it be a typo ofr `g/=2`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta WOWOWOW u r a life saver thank you

Comment: your compiler can be a life saver too, if you just pay attention to warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/cr9e9v

Answer (score 0):

for(int g = gap; g >= 1; g/2)

it has to be (g+1)/2 and it should exit the loop after executing for gap=1 once.